# CSS z-index is not working with element which parent has transform:translate3d

Tags: javascript, html, css

**Environment**

Browser: Chrome Version 69.0.3497.92 (Official Build) (64-bit)

Components: ganlanyuan/tiny-slider found [here](https://github.com/ganlanyuan/tiny-slider)

**Background:**

I have a slider created using tiny-slider. It works well. Also on the same page, I have an overlay div which overlays the whole page.

**The Issue:**

The exact problem is, On my slider I have an element (I am calling it the active element) which should be seen over the 'overlay' layer. Which means all other slider item should be under the overlay except the active element.

I am giving the overlay `z-index: 999` and active item `z-index: 9999`.
Technically we expect that the active comes in front of the overlay. But it doesn't.

What I Expect to get:
[image]

What I actually get:
[image]

I am aware of that this issue is because the slider uses `transform:translate3d` to move the items left and right which is canceling the `z-index`.

I have read most solutions that I found on google but no luck.

I regenerated this problem on codepen. here is the link https://codepen.io/peshraw-h-ahmed/pen/pOZNdg. 
Is there any solution for that problem? Can anyone tell me where the problem is and fix it inside the codepen snippet.

The Codes:

```js
tns({
  "container": ".base",
  "items": 4,
  autoplay: false,
  "nav": false,
  "slideBy": "page",
  "mouseDrag": true,
  "swipeAngle": false,
  "speed": 400
})
```

```css
.overlay {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.7);
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  color: #fff;
  z-index: 999;
}

.item {
  background: #e67e22;
  height: 450px;
  color: #fff;
  border: 1px solid;
}
.item.active {
  z-index: 9999;
  background: #2c3e50;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/tiny-slider/2.8.6/tiny-slider.css">

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/tiny-slider/2.8.6/min/tiny-slider.js"></script>

<div class="base">
  <div class="item">Item</div>
  <div class="item active">Active Item</div>
  <div class="item">Item</div>
  <div class="item">Item</div>
  <div class="item">Item</div>
  <div class="item">Item</div>
  <div class="item">Item</div>
  <div class="item">Item</div>
  <div class="item">Item</div>
  <div class="item">Item</div>
  <div class="item">Item</div>
  <div class="item">Item</div>
</div>

<div class="overlay">
   Overlay
</div>
```

Comment: you have also another issue, you are applying z-index to a static element, not positioned ... and if you aren't able to get rid of the transform, you have no way to do it

Comment: Actually I was focusing on regenerating the problem on codepen. You are right. On my main code the element is positioned relatively. There should be a way. Otherwise I have to change the slider system inside the whole system which needs too much time :/

Comment: Your overlay is higher than the stacking order of the `base` elements. So no matter how high you put the the the `active` item, the overlay is always going to be higher. If you make the overlay have a `z-index` of -1 it should work as intended. I'm not going to put this as an answer because it's late here, so I'm too tired to check and might end up with 300 downvotes, haha!

Comment: @InvariantChange whataver the value of z-index you add to the overlay it won't work because the transfrom create a stacking context which is self-contained So you can place nothing between its elements unless the placed element belong to the same stacking context

Comment: @InvariantChange Ahah. You will definitely get 500 downvotes :D because making z-index of the overlay -1 will put the overlay under all items. not the active one. Thank you for making me laugh by the way :))

Comment: Fuzzy logic. If the overlay uses JavaScript to get the next highest index, say: `var zindex=document.defaultView.getComputedStyle(elems[i],null).getPropertyValue("z-index");` then it will work. But like I said. Too tired to check.

Comment: And it was 300 downvotes, not 500. I can't believe how mean people are. :( Haha! Jokes :p

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can change the overlay so it belong to the stacking context generated by the transform and you will be able to make the active element above it:

```js
tns({
  "container": ".base",
  "items": 4,
  autoplay: false,
  "nav": false,
  "slideBy": "page",
  "mouseDrag": true,
  "swipeAngle": false,
  "speed": 400
})
```

```css
/*the Overlay*/
.base:before {
  content:"";
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.7);
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  color: #fff;
  z-index: 999;
}
/**/
.item {
  background: #e67e22;
  height: 450px;
  color: #fff;
  border: 1px solid;
  position:relative;
}
.item.active {
  z-index: 9999;
  background: #2c3e50;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/tiny-slider/2.8.6/tiny-slider.css">

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/tiny-slider/2.8.6/min/tiny-slider.js"></script>

<div class="base">
  <div class="item">Item</div>
  <div class="item active">Active Item</div>
  <div class="item">Item</div>
  <div class="item">Item</div>
  <div class="item">Item</div>
  <div class="item">Item</div>
  <div class="item">Item</div>
  <div class="item">Item</div>
  <div class="item">Item</div>
  <div class="item">Item</div>
  <div class="item">Item</div>
  <div class="item">Item</div>
</div>
```

Comment: A nice approach. Can't wait to go home and test it on my codes. Thank you anyway :)